# Is window shading unavailable in Wayland (KDE)?

Tags: x11, kde, wayland

I just updated to Fedora 34 from 33, and now we have Wayland instead of X. But suddenly I can no longer shade my windows. If I right click on a title bar and go to "More Actions", I can maximize, minimize, etc. but "Shade" is greyed out.

Is this just not available in Wayland?

I also run KDE, so I think the appropriate versions are:

xorg-x11-server-Xwayland-21.1.1-1.fc34.x86_64 kwin-wayland-5.21.5-2.fc34.x86_64 plasma-workspace-wayland-5.21.5-3.fc34.x86_64

Searches for "Linux Wayland" and "shade" or "shading" are coming up empty for me.

Comment: Is the problem solved ?

Comment: As of 15 Feb. 2020, the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kwayland/html/classKWayland_1_1Client_1_1PlasmaWindowModel.html it seems (if the API version is the same thing as Plasma Workspace version) that it will be available in 5.22:

> IsShadeable
> Since    5.22
>
> IsShaded
> Since    5.22

Comment: Great! Thanks @marek77. Fedora 34 has Plasma 5.21, so we're getting close...

Comment: Still no luck in kwin 5.24 on Artix